# Always eager load relation in Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have already tried to search for this problem, I did not find a solution.

In Laravel (PHP) you can define the following on a ORM (Eloquent) model:

```php
class User extends Eloquent
{
    protected $with = ['roles'];
}
```

In the example, querying for a `User` will *always* eager load the `roles` relation (not defined in the example).

I want to do the same with Sequelize.js for Node.

Can you define auto-eager loading (included) releations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can uses [scopes](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/scopes.html) to achieve this, they support `include` and you can define a `defaultScope`.

For example (code not tested but should give you the idea you need to implement this in your own code):

```js
const Role = sequelize.define('role', { 
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
}, { 
    timestamps: false,
});

const User = sequelize.define('user', { 
    name: DataTypes.STRING 
}, { 
    timestamps: false,
    defaultScope: {
        include: Role,
    }, 
});

User.hasMany(Role);
Role.belongsTo(User);
```